# anchor float right of ul

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

```
<nav style="width:100%">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="####.html" style="border-left:1px solid #FFF;">****</a></li>
      <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
      <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
      <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
      <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
   </ul>
   <a href="####.html"><img src="####.jpg" alt="lang:ger" style="float:right;"></a>
   <a href="home.html"><img src="./../../img/english.jpg" alt="lang:eng" style="float:right;"></a>
</nav>
```

I would like to have the two links after the `<ul>` to float right of the `<ul>`, but in the same line. So far all my attempts ended up being to the right but in the next line. How can I float those links?

Comment: A <ul> is a block item by default, meaning it's going to take up 100% of its container's width. Set it to display: inline; or give it a set width.

Comment: did you try to float the UL left?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LQpgC/

Comment: Is this what you were tring to do ???

Comment: @MannfromReno post your answer as an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just float the UL left:

HTML:

```
<nav style="width:100%">
<ul>
  <li><a href="####.html" style="border-left:1px solid #FFF;">****</a></li>
  <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
  <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
  <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
  <li><a href="####.html">****</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="####.html"><img src="####.jpg" alt="lang:ger" style="float:right;"></a>
<a href="home.html"><img src="./../../img/english.jpg" alt="lang:eng"   style="float:right;"></a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  float: left;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ec28U/